# Java equivalent of COM

Tags: java, com, ipc

I'm developing a Java app that will run as two processes that need to communicate. I want to avoid pipes, sockets and things like that. I'm looking for something like COM, something that will allow me to share an object between two processes (I know that it may be more involved than just "sharing", for example with COM this requires marshalling and RPC).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid sockets and pipes?

Comment: Well because they are too primitive and require you to do everything by hand, so you end up with your own mini-protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about [com](/questions/tagged/com), but in Java world [rmi](/questions/tagged/rmi) is the built-in first choice when communicating between two JVMs. In principle it's an object-oriented implementation of [rpc](/questions/tagged/rpc). Underneath it uses TCP/IP and Java serialization + [jndi](/questions/tagged/jndi) for discovery.